# Rake for .NET

Tags: .net, rake

What is the best way to build a .NET solution and run MbUnit tests using Rake?

I'm currently invoking commands directly like this:

```
sh "#{DOT_NET_PATH}msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=#{CONFIG} #{SOLUTION}"
```

This works but seems a bit rubbish. Are there any gems people would recommend using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just started using albacore which is available on http://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore.

Full docs at the [wiki](http://wiki.github.com/derickbailey/Albacore)

Your task for executing a build is this simple:

```
msbuild do |msb|
 msb.solution = "mysolution.sln"
 #... other settings here
end
```

Want to execute unit tests?

```
desc "NUnit Test Runner Example"
nunit do |nunit|
    nunit.path_to_command = "NUnit/nunit-console.exe"
    nunit.assemblies << "assemblies/TestSolution.Tests.dll"
end
```

UPDATE:
Check out [this May 2010 article](http://code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?QuickID=1006101) for a very comprehensive tutorial.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this myself now. It's great. If I'd remembered this question I'd have added this answer myself.

Comment: You might want to come back and edit this question soon as the syntax is going to be changing slightly to just "nunit" instead of "nunittask".

Answer (score 4):

[rake-dotnet](http://www.neverrunwithscissors.com/development/tools/2009/04/03/raking-it-in-rake-dotnet-hello-world-release-v005.html) is pretty useful, if rather new (though that's admittedly pretty shameless of me ;-)  ).

[Source code](http://github.com/petemounce/rake-dotnet)

Comment: I should say - I don't support rake-dotnet at this point, you should use albacore instead.